# python matrix manipulation - square each element

Tags: python, list, matrix, list-comprehension

How do I take a matrix such as:

matrix = [[2,0,2],[0,2,0],[2,0,2]] and transform it to [[4,0,4],[0,4,0],[4,0,4]]

where all the elements in the list become squared? I'm trying to do list comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> lis = [[2,0,2],[0,2,0],[2,0,2]]
>>> [[y**2 for y in x] for x in lis]
[[4, 0, 4], [0, 4, 0], [4, 0, 4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org):

```
import numpy as np

matrix = [[2,0,2],[0,2,0],[2,0,2]]
np_matrix = np.array(matrix)
np_matrix**2
```

A list comprehension could look like this

```
matrix2 = [
    [e*e for e in l]
    for l in matrix
]
```

Comment: Exponentiating a matrix like `np_matrix ** 2` is a different operation from exponentiating each element separately.

Comment: Not, if you us `np.array` for constructing a numpy array. You are right that it would correspond to a matrix square, if `np.matrix` was used.

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions can be nested:

```
sqd = [[elem*elem for elem in inner] for inner in outer]
```

In this case `outer` would be your matrix `matrix`

```
>>>> matrix = [[2,0,2],[0,2,0],[2,0,2]]
>>>> sqd = [[elem*elem for elem in inner] for inner in matrix]
>>>> sqd
[[4, 0, 4], [0, 4, 0], [4, 0, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by

```
matrix = [[2,0,2],[0,2,0],[2,0,2]]
```

a list of lists, then do the following

```
import numpy as np
np.square(matrix)
```

This gives you output as follows:

```
array([[4, 0, 4],
       [0, 4, 0],
       [4, 0, 4]], dtype=int32)
```

However, if you really mean it to be a matrix, you have to create a matrix first as follows:

```
X = np.matrix('2 0 2; 0 2 0;  2 0 2')
```

and then do the same as above, i.e.,

```
np.square(X)
```

This gives you the desired output as follows:

```
[[4 0 4]
 [0 4 0]
 [4 0 4]]
```